# How do I use a value that is returned from a Macro Variable in another macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have simplified this a lot so it can be repeated

```
%macro macro_one(dt2);
  %let var1 = &dt2;
%mend;
```

Then I have another macro and I want to use the output from macro one in macro 2

```
%macro macro_print(dt2);
  /*call macro 1*/
  %macro_one(&dt2);
  %put &var1;
%mend;
```

/*call macro*/

```
%macro_print('purple');
```

It should print purple in the logs but I get an error
I get an error though - i suspect I need to assign the macro variable from macro one when I call macro two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I suspect you have a typo between your code and here.  Proper way to define a macro is:

```
%macro blah(x);
<do stuff>
%mend;
```

not:

```
%macro_blah(x);
<do stuff>
%mend;
```

The macro is created in `%macro_one` and defaults to a local scope.  You can fix this by declaring it `%global`.

```
%macro macro_one(dt2);
   %global var1;
   %let var1=&dt2;
%mend;
```

Also, use `%put` not `put` in `%macro_two`.

Comment: sorry my quick typing, i am ammending now

Comment: This is really great. Is there a way to make this work if my macro variables are being defined in the data step within a macro.. i.e. using SYMPUTX

Comment: The macro variable with SYMPUTX is global by default. But the macro variable can't be used within the same dataset.

Comment: Note Dom says *can*.  You probably *should* not do this in most cases.

Comment: @DaJunTian That's not correct (the first part).  Symput puts the macro variable in the [most local nonempty symbol table](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#tw3514-symput.htm), which can be either the local table or the global table (or a local table of a macro that called the current macro, or anywhere up a chain).  `SYMPUTX` allows you to specify the symbol table (scope) as a third optional argument.

Comment: This makes sense. I forget about this. Thanks Joe.